# How can I connect slider to redux in react native?

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to hook up the slider to the redux because I have added slider to the settings screen so idea behind is user to be able to use the radius in the two other screens where I am using google places api and one of the parameters is radius so I want them be able to filter change the radius with the slider. I am currently facing following error when trying to drag the slider.

error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.value')`

```
<Slider
          style={slider}
          trackStyle={sliderTrack}
          thumbStyle={sliderThumb}
          minimumValue={10}
          maximumValue={100}
          step={10}
          value={props.radius}
          onValueChange={(e) => props.sliderActions.sliderAction(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Text>Alue: {props.radius} km</Text>
```

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  radius: state.sliderReducer.radius,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  sliderActions: bindActionCreators(sliderAction, dispatch),
});
```

this is the action file for the slider and not sure if this is part of the issue:

```
const SLIDER_SET_VALUE = 'SLIDER_SET_VALUE'

export const sliderAction = (value) => ({
    type: SLIDER_SET_VALUE,
    payload: value
})
```

Here in reducer I have set the initial value of radius to 10 which is also not showing in the text below the slider:

```
const SLIDER_SET_VALUE = 'SLIDER_SET_VALUE'

const initialState = {
  radius: 10,
}

const sliderValueReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SLIDER_SET_VALUE:
      return {
        ...state,
        radius: action.payload,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default sliderValueReducer
```

and this index of reducer where I have combined the reducers to rootReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import { ModalReducer } from './modalReducer'
import sliderValueReducer from './sliderReducer'

// Redux: Root Reducer
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  modalReducer: ModalReducer,
  sliderReducer: sliderValueReducer
})
// Exports
export default rootReducer
```

and also in my log I do receive the initial state of the radius.

```
LOG    %c prev state color: #9E9E9E; font-weight: bold {"modalReducer": {"id": ""}, "sliderReducer": {"radius": 10}}
LOG    %c action     color: #03A9F4; font-weight: bold {"register": [Function register], "rehydrate": [Function rehydrate], "type": "persist/PERSIST"}
LOG    %c next state color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold {"_persist": {"rehydrated": false, "version": -1}, "modalReducer": {"id": ""}, "sliderReducer": {"radius": 10}}
```

Here is console log for the `(e) => console.log(e)`

```
LOG  0
 LOG  10
 LOG  10
 LOG  10
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
 LOG  20
```

Comment: Could you change `onValueChange={(e) => props.sliderActions.sliderAction(e.target.value)}` to `onValueChange={(e) => console.log(e)}` and add the output to your question?

Comment: Updated the question with the log. It seems to give me the values. @MaartenDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onValueChange` property of the `<Slider />` component only provides the new slider value. It does not provide an Event. Because of this you cannot access the `e.target.value`. You can however directly use the value:

```
<Slider
   style={slider}
   trackStyle={sliderTrack}
   thumbStyle={sliderThumb}
   minimumValue={10}
   maximumValue={100}
   step={10}
   value={props.radius}
   onValueChange={(newValue) => props.sliderActions.sliderAction(newValue)} // Use value directly
/>
```

Comment: Ah I see. How about displaying the value below the slider?

Comment: nvm figured it out it was .radius and not .value after sliderReducer ```const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  radius: state.sliderReducer.radius,
});
```

Comment: yep, you can access it using the props from `mapStateToProps`. Good luck!